# How to access a DIV that is inside a Telerik RadGrid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a div with its own id in the ItemTemplate of a GridTemplateColumn of a RadGrid.
 How can I access this div from the code behind?
If it was a div in the web page I could access it just by typing its id but this method does not work now that it is nested inside the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this example.

in Aspx page

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn> 
      <ItemTemplate> 
            <div id="divlayer" runat="server"> 
              Hello             
            </div> 
       </ItemTemplate> 
  </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

In CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) 
    { 
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem) 
        { 
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item; 
            HtmlGenericControl container = (HtmlGenericControl)item.FindControl("divlayer"); 
        } 
    }
```

Hope it might help you..